# want stand logic app or function app (not premium) to connect to a blob storage which is under a vnet. How to achieve this?

Tags: azure, blob

we have function app/ consumption logic app that read/write to a blob storage. it works if blob storage network is set to pulic access .  But it is not working if we change the blob storage to allow only from within network.

how to achieve this.
thanks for your help

making both the consumption logic app and function as premium then we have the outbound network settings. this works

Comment: If both storage account and the standard logic apps are in same region then you can access the storage account from logic apps through Http action. You can refer to sample [blog post here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/access-storage-accounts-behind-firewalls-from-logic-apps-within/ba-p/1997801). If both the resources are in different region refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage?tabs=consumption#access-storage-accounts-behind-firewalls) for more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.